# Node JS routing

Tags: node.js, module, routes, export

Assume I have app.js as

```
var express=require('express');
var app= express();
app.get('/',function(req,res){...});
```

It is possible to make a route outside this file by using middleware (use) in two different ways:

**First method :**

use app.js as following:

```
var express=require('express');
var app= express();
app.use('/',require('myRouter'))
```

inside myRouter.js

```
var express=require('express');
var router=express.Router();
router.get('/',function(req,res){...});
module.export=router;
```

**Second method:**

use app.js as following:

```
var express=require('express');
var app= express();
app.use('/',require('myRouter')(app))
```

inside myRouter.js

```
module.exports=function(app){
 app.get('/',function(req,res){...});
}
```

My question is related to compare First and Second methods and which one is the best. 
Am I correct that in the first method we are defining express variable again (so we will have two express variable one in app.js and one in myRouter.js) ? or are these two express variables are the same when the whole application compiles in nodejs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Express is an **unopinionated** framework which means there is no right or wrong in designing app structure. It is up to the developer.

When you require express again and again inside multiple modules, you get the **same** **reference**, so you need not worry about it. In your example, both are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users', users);


// in users

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', userController.register);

....
module.exports = router;
```